# jquery string concatenation in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

i want to concat some string(id) with parent id...
so i'v **tried** this-------------->

```
$(' #cate_id2 > ul > li:has(ul) ').hover(function () {
                $('#cate_id2 > ul' + this + ' > ul').stop().slideDown('fast');
            },
```

want to **concat** `#cate_id2 > ul` with `this` and than **append** `> ul` ....

string should becomes after execute `'#cate_id2 > ul' + li:has(ul) + ' > ul'`
                                        i mean **`li:has(ul)` will replaced by with its value.......**

Comment: this makes 0 since, please rerite

Comment: This sounds like a very convoluted method. What is it you're actually trying to do with the selector? I'm 99% sure there's a better way using traversal.

Comment: In the "hover" handler, you can use `$(this).children("ul")` to find and act on the child `<ul>` elements.

Answer (score 4):

Try it like this

```
$(' #cate_id2 > ul > li:has(ul) ').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown('fast');
}
```

Comment: Wow. Do you have a PhD in understanding gibberish?

Comment: ... or `.children("ul")` to capture the "> ul" from the original weirdness.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan don't read the text, just the code :) From the desired outcome string it SUDDENLY becomes clear that the OP wants just a direct `ul` child of the element he already selected :)